# Grid View Insert to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, insert

First time attempting C#. I am creating a Web Form that uploads an excel sheet into a SQL Server database table. It first uploads a selected file, and displays the data on a Grid View with the press of a "Preview" button. From there, it is then inserted into a database table, on my local SQL server, with the press of an "upload" button.

So far I am having trouble matching the data from the Grid View to the table. The data will always change and never be the same number of rows. Any suggestions? My code for this is a s follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"USE [PD_Overview] INSERT INTO [dbo].['LABTEST$']
                    ([EmployeeID]
                    ,[Company]
                    ,[Employee Name]
                    ,[Start Time]
                    ,[Signature In]
                    ,[Lunch IN]
                    ,[Lunch OUT]
                    ,[End Time]
                    ,[Hours]
                    ,[Job]
                    ,[Period]
                    ,[Date]
                    ,[PayID]
                    ,[Equipment Used]
                    ,[Injured ?]
                    ,[Signature OUT]
                    ,[Superintendent]
                    ,[Processed By]
                    ,[Date Processed]
                    ,[On Time or Late - Proc]
                    ,[Reported By]
                    ,[Date Reported]
                    ,[Hours Late-Rpt]
                    ,[Job % Complete]
                    ,[Variances]
                    ,[Unique ID]
                    ,[RT Hours WTD]
                    ,[RT Hours Daily]
                    ,[OT Hours Daily]
                    ,[RT $ Daily]
                    ,[OT $ Daily]
                    ,[Total $ Daily]
                    ,[PERDIEM $ Daily ]
                    ,[HOURS(No PerDiem)]
                    ,[ID]
                    ,[SORT]) VALUES('" + GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0] + "','" + GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1] + "')"
```

Comment: The manner in which you are trying to do this with raw SQL -- you are only providing data for two of the columns (EmployeeID, Company).  Try providing data for each of the remaining columns in the `VALUES()` argument

Comment: Obligatory warning about SQL injection attacks and string concatenation. Use parameters instead! It also looks like you have invalid column names, where did you get those column names from? The ones with symbols and spaces must be enclosed in back-ticks, but I'm not sure you can even use % and $, or -...

Comment: Thank you @Fraze I added the the additional and it seemed to work. Now just a conversion error of dates.

Comment: @RonBeyer How so about the parameters? Recommend any material to read on this? I am new to coding. The names are the column headers of the excel sheets being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use a same code like this

```
public void Test()
    {
        //you can see all type of connection string for sql server in https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/
        //example of connection string for sql server
        //Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
        SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("your connection string");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        string commandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].['LABTEST$']([EmployeeID],[Company],[Employee Name],[Start Time]"+
            ",[Signature In],[Lunch IN],[Lunch OUT],[End Time],[Hours],[Job],[Period],[Date],[PayID],[Equipment Used],[Injured ?]"+
            ",[Signature OUT],[Superintendent],[Processed By],[Date Processed],[On Time or Late - Proc],[Reported By],[Date Reported]"+
            ",[Hours Late-Rpt],[Job % Complete],[Variances],[Unique ID],[RT Hours WTD],[RT Hours Daily],[OT Hours Daily],[RT $ Daily]"+
            ",[OT $ Daily],[Total $ Daily],[PERDIEM $ Daily ],[HOURS(No PerDiem)],[ID],[SORT]) VALUES(@EmployeeID,@Company)";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            cmd=new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            cmd = null;
        }
    }
```